# Math videos containing real time rough thinking

Tags: soft-question, gm.general-mathematics

I find this [vlog experiment of Gowers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=byjhpzEoXFs) very brave, and I think his idea of having examples of real-time mathematical thinking by experts can be very encouraging for young mathematicians, who imagine the pace of the greats is impossibly far and away above that of mere mortals when they meet new problems. (Online comments by Borcherds, as well as this wonderfully courageous experiment by Gowers suggest otherwise.) A funny anecdote along these lines: Once a graduate student said to me: "I have an image of Terry Tao eating his breakfast one morning, eating his cereal, and as he lifts his spoon to his mouth he pauses, looks off into the distance, and in that moment does more productive mathematics than I will in my entire lifetime."

Have others participated in this experiment? Are there other online video examples of "real time raw thinking" by leading mathematicians, following up on Gowers's experiment above?

Whether this question should be on MO is undoubtedly going to be controversial but I think it has to do with mathematical practice, and particularly the working styles of top mathematicians who frequent this forum.

Comment: Is "the pace of the greats" even a well-defined topic? I think what you typically see among great mathematicians, or average mathematicians who have attained expertise in a particular topic, is that some questions they are able to solve very quickly at a speed that seems magical and other questions they take a long time on or can't solve at all.  There are also of course differences between great mathematicians - Terry Tao writes a lot of papers quickly, but there are plenty of equally great mathematicians who prefer to write fewer papers.

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking for, but perhaps in the same spirit, are Terry Tao's [account of his generals](https://web.math.princeton.edu/generals/tao_terence) and his *Notices* article [A Close Call: How a Near Failure Propelled Me to Succeed](https://www.ams.org/journals/notices/202007/rnoti-p1007.pdf).

Comment: The problem is that the solution often really comes in a flash, so there is a sharp transition from blind poking and moving in random directions to a fully developed argument and for me the most interesting question would be what triggers that transition. Unfortunately, this triggering mechanism is more often than not relying on something that occurs behind the scenes: long branching chains of associations with few explicitly pronounced words. @WillSawin "plenty of equally great mathematicians"? Hmm.. I can name a few, of course, but I suspect that "plenty" is quite an exaggeration. :-)

Comment: @fedja I think I meant plenty for the purposes of this discussion. But maybe I should have said "incomparable" in the partial order sense, rather than "equal".

Comment: @WillSawin Meaning "mathematicians whose ways of thinking would be equally interesting to observe"? Yeah, I can agree to this statement. :-)

Comment: I watched the beginning of the video and I doubt Gowers is doing his real thinking rather than emulating that of a very inexperienced undergraduate student: only the latter would attempt to compute any large determinant from the definition and the explicit formula for the entries. Anybody with any experience in linear algebra when seeing the first column of 1s would just subtract the previous row from the current one starting from the bottom and that would finish the problem in no time. So I take it as a movie about how Gowers thinks an undergrad would think, which is not very interesting IMHO

Comment: If what fedja says is true, then I agree the video is uninteresting. If, on the other hand, it is not, and Gowers is honestly thinking about these things at this speed, then it is very interesting to me for reasons that are perhaps obvious and not appropriate to elaborate. It may be that @gowers can disambiguate this?

Comment: @JonBannon It is not even about *speed*. It is just that "the first thought that comes into one's head" is always to use the trick that worked most often in a similar situation and I cannot name a single instance in my experience where the computation of a large determinant from definition would lead anywhere. Notice also how he hesitates about how to compute the 3 by 3 case: I refuse to believe that one isn't tempted to subtract at least the first row from the other two, but that would already reveal too much! And then he sweeps the computation of 4 by 4 under the rug entirely.

Comment: In other words, Gowers willingly suppresses *all his prior experience and intuition* at least in the beginning and that suppression *is* detectable, which casts the doubt on whether the declared goal of showing the thought process as it is is really pursued here. I cannot prove anything, of course, but, unfortunately, @gowers won't be able to disprove my statements either. Nobody except himself will ever know for sure how the movie was really made. I'm just saying that it *looks* grossly incongruous *to me* and am trying to clearly explain why :-)

Answer (score 13):

When I taught a beginners course in analysis a few years ago I wanted to give the students an impression of how one can work on exam problems. I asked somebody to prepare a test exam (I had my exam prepared already and asked for an exam in a similar style). I got the exam in a closed envelope and walked into an empty lecture hall with a blackboard and document camera. There I recorded myself solving the exam problems thinking out loud all the time. I first went through the problems, commented on then, then went to the blackboard and started solving them and once I was seeing how I should do it, I went to the document camera and wrote down the solution as I would write them to get full marks. I posted the video uncut for the students. It was actually a nice experience for me and I got a lot of feedback saying that this was very helpful for the preparation of the exam (and also it helped some people with "test anxiety" - if that is the correct word in English…).

Comment: I usually run such review sessions "live" before qualifiers, meaning that I come to class and let the students throw any problems at me (they take it from old exams, from internet, whatever). I also solve the problems on the fly thinking at the board and, once (or, rather, if: I failed a couple of times) I figure them out end with showing how I would present them. Recording such session and letting someone else to create a full exam is actually a great idea. I'm willing to try it before our next quals. Can you post the link to your video so that I can look at how you've done it?

Comment: Of course, one problem with this approach is that you often see the solution more or less immediately (I doubt an exam problem from "beginner analysis course" would normally present a real challenge to you), so I suspect that what you show is more about how to organize your thinking and writing rather than how to find solutions but even that can be of tremendous help to the students, I agree here. So thanks for sharing the idea and thanks in advance for the video if you decide to share it too! :-)

Comment: We have an installed recording system in the classrooms and the recordings appear in our teaching management system behind a login. Moreover, they are in German… I could try to download them and upload them somewhere else, if you would be interested.

Comment: German is not a big problem by itself: I used to be able to read mathematical papers in German though I haven't practiced it for years (Warum? "Morgen, Morgen, nur nicht Heute" - sagen alle foul Leute :-) )  Besides, I need just to get a clear idea of how you do it rather than the details on every single problem you solve there, so even Chinese might work to some extent. So yeah, I am interested if it is not too much trouble for you :-)

Comment: Here is a link: https://youtu.be/ldo6P1BO2HY. While downloading and uploading, the quality got worse, but I hope you can see what was going on…

Comment: Almost. It says "private video, please sign in" on opening. Apparently you need to change the permissions to make it viewable to other people.

Comment: I hope it works now.

Answer (score 5):

I feel that after what I said I should offer something constructive here as well. Part of the problem with such movies is that the very act of verbalizing the thought process interferes with it quite severely. At the very least it significantly slows you down (take any computer program you ever wrote for computing something interesting, add the command to print the result after every operation, and watch it running). But that is not all. Interrupting a human thought is worse than interrupting a computer program because most of us are incapable of storing a SSW at the moment of interruption and retrieving it without error once the interruption is over. Also, when talking, we feel like we need to exhibit some clear logic in our transitions, while in fact many of them occur merely because one chain of thoughts suddenly outpaces the other, so we just switch to a more promising approach, and so on, and so forth.

So, simultaneous verbalization is a killer. What to do then? The only way out I see is to think it all through in the usual way and then post *all that we wrote on paper in the order of writing* with some short comments about the places that would look totally unclear to an outsider. That is like having a fossil record of your thought that tells about it as much as fragments of dinosaur bones about the terrible lizards themselves, which is not everything, but still quite a lot. Here is mine for the same problem. What I had in front of my eyes at the moment of writing was the screen with 4 first determinants, out of which only the last one really mattered, i.e., I was looking at
$$
\begin{matrix}
1&1&1&1
\\
1&2&3&4
\\
1&3&6&10
\\
1&4&10&20
\end{matrix}
$$
What I wrote is here:
[image: writing]
(the top scribbled line reads "row - part. sums of prev. rows?").
The rest should be clear from my comments.

I feel like I have to add in the end that it doesn't mean that my thinking is better than that of Gowers. In fact, IMHO, compared to him, I am a hopeless imbecile sliding into senility. It merely means that I believe that the movie he posted does not (and, as conceived, could possibly not) reflect his true thinking. Also, to speak frankly, the Terry Tao's blog post titled "Does one have to be a genius to do maths?" reminds me of the phrase "Superman just helps now and then" in the famous cartoon. It is all fine, but if you watch that cartoon with a timer in hand, you'll realize that this "now and then" occupies about 90% of the shown events and the corresponding percentage in Terry's published papers is fairly close. As to his "generals", his account, if you translate it into layman language, reads to me "On my test I had to jump over the Empire State building and I almost knocked the spire off plus made a couple of unnecessary extra steps when landing, which showed to me that I need some more training before I attempt an unaided flight to the stratosphere". Disagree? Then try to pass his test yourself right now. You have enough information about what the questions were in his post, so just sit down and honestly write the answers to the best of your abilities. If you get happy with the result, let me know. I'm willing to take your word for it. But I give you mine that I failed miserably :-)

I am as curious about how great minds work as the OP, so if somebody has a good idea of how to observe that thought process, I will be happy to hear it. I also admire Tim Gowers for his attempt despite the fact that I still firmly believe that the way he approached it was hopelessly doomed from the beginning unless the true goal was very different from the proclaimed one.

Comment: I mostly agree, but the discussion of Tao’s post confuses me and distracts from the clarity of the other things you say.

Comment: @fedja: This is something that has fascinated me for years. Somehow thinking about math (productively) is highly intuitive and nonverbal. It's possible to "mumble" while working and not interrupt the intuition, but outright verbalization and even writing can interrupt key aspects of the process. Somehow writing formulas isn't as bad as sentences for this, though. On the other hand, it seems that sometimes writing/recording seems to slow things down enough to direct the intuition productively. I can sort of feel some of this happening in Gowers's video.

Comment: to paraphrase something Thurston mentioned about "listening" to his mind...it seems that doing math might be more about listening than talking. But I am not so *sure* about this. I am not sure it is impossible to do math and report on what you are thinking at the same time....

Comment: It may depend strongly on the individual mathematician. Hadamard's survey/study on this indicates the nonverbal approach is far and away the most common....

Comment: "try to pass his test yourself right now" is irrelevant. I can't pass the harmonic analysis portion, because I never studied harmonic analysis. But I'm pretty sure I could if I had a year to prepare, because I passed a similar test after a year of preparation. So could most mathematicians! (Most mathematicians passed some kind of exam in grad school of roughly similar difficulty, and could do better now.) The point of the story is that Terry didn't study enough and thus didn't do well on the test (though he did pass), i.e. that Terry needed to study to do well, just like the rest of us.

Comment: To underscore this point, note that on the algebra section of the exam, I can think of plenty of mathematicians who could easily do better than Terry did, by answering the following questions without help: "Talk about Galois theory", "Construct a field extension of order S_n.", "Construct one of order A_n", "What else do you know about A_n?" (I think you're supposed to read "Galois group" for "order" but maybe it's supposed to be "degree n!" and "degree n!/2" or something.) These are not hard questions for anyone whose research intersects Galois theory.

Comment: But Terry passed the algebra section without complaint, even though plenty of people would do better than him on algebra and worse on harmonic analysis. So you  can't evaluate how difficult his achievement on the test was in a vacuum, you have to do it in the context of what he studied.

Comment: @WillSawin Yep, you've made quite a good point here (about the "context of what he studied") and, of course, the moral you propose is entirely correct *at any level*. But I still maintain that the level of his generals was very high and the scope very wide compared to everything I've seen. Our analysis qualifiers are *much* simpler and still the students struggle a lot despite they *do* study for them for a couple of years. But MattF is right. I shouldn't have mixed two topics. Well, the mistake has been made; too late to correct it now :-)

Comment: @MattF. I mentioned Terry Tao just because his "account of his generals" was mentioned as something relevant in the comments, but, as I said in the response to Will Savin, you are completely right when saying that I shouldn't mix two topics. Indeed, when I look at my post now, that part (whether one agrees with it or not) does distract one from the main points of the message I tried to convey. :-)

Comment: My impression is that Tao's generals were no harder than anyone else's at Princeton on average. I would actually posit that reading Princeton alumni's account of their own generals is a fairly good example of what the OP wants (albeit, it's text not video) -- the only caveat is that I have often found the people writing them are too humble about how they performed in the exam.

Comment: Here's the link for finding other people's accounts: https://web.math.princeton.edu/generals/

Comment: @fedja I do not agree that this video cannot reflect Gowers's true thinking (modulo the fact that he wouldn't be talking out loud). I did not watch the whole thing, but what he did was close to what I would have done. The first thing I usually do is to numerically check that the claim is true. At minimum, this ensures that I have the statement correct. So I would certainly check the 3x3 case, and it's faster for me to do that by hand than to use the computer. I'd probably check the 4x4 case too; I'd use a computer, but some people I know enjoy hand computations and might do that by hand too.

Comment: Of course, doing row reductions is a pretty obvious thing to do as well, but Gowers didn't dilly-dally very long before doing row reductions. That's about as far as I watched, and I didn't see anything artificial. Now maybe all this proves is that my problem-solving ability is no better than that of an average undergraduate. I won't try to argue that point, but I work in a rather collaborative problem-solving environment and have observed my colleagues thinking out loud (and some of them are excellent problem solvers) and Gowers's video doesn't seem that far off.